# $quote_item_option = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item_option')->load('1')->group('item_id'); - Not working

Tags: magento-1.7

```
Array
 (


    [0] => Array
    (
        [option_id] => 111584
        [item_id] => 50399
        [product_id] => 855
        [code] => info_buyRequest
        [value] => a:11:{s:4:"uenc";s:76:"aHR0cDovLzE5Mi4xNjguMS4yNDMvbmV3X2NhbmRlcmUvYWRoeWEtZGlhbW9uZC1yaW5nLmh0bWw,";s:7:"product";s:3:"855";s:15:"related_product";s:0:"";s:13:"extra_options";a:7:{s:21:"Metal Weight (Approx)";s:4:"2.09";s:3:"sku";s:7:"C003440";s:13:"Diamond Color";s:2:"GH";s:15:"Diamond Clarity";s:2:"SI";s:5:"Metal";s:11:"Yellow Gold";s:6:"Purity";s:3:"18K";s:9:"Ring Size";s:23:"4        13.8mm";}s:13:"custom_params";a:3:{s:14:"estimated_date";s:18:"September 26, 2016";s:19:"total_weight_approx";s:4:"2.13";s:24:"selected_making_discount";i:1254;}s:13:"product_price";s:5:"23317";s:15:"email1_wishlist";s:0:"";s:21:"userPassword_wishlist";s:0:"";s:17:"diamond_selection";s:8:"34066.00";s:18:"customized_product";s:0:"";s:3:"qty";i:1;}
    )

)
```

How to print this above `value` field?

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you want in more detail.

Comment: @Arjun  I have a record in sales_flat_quote_item_option table. Now I want to show or print that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont Understand you proper but according to me what I understand from that you can try below code

```
$quote_item_option = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item_option')->getCollection()
                     ->addFieldToFilter('item_id',1);
print_r ($quote_item_option->getData()); 
foreach($quote_item_option->getData() as $coll){
   $value_data =  json_decode($coll->getValue(), true); // it will give you json as array then iterate array and you will get Qty value 
   print_r($value_data);
}
```

Try above code and let me know its working or not

Comment: It is not working. I have a record in sales_flat_quote_item_option table. Now I want to show or print  that value.

Comment: `print_r($quote_item_option->getData());` and try

Comment: Actually I want to fire a query where I have item_id 's value . So how to write sql query?

Comment: In that how to print qty field

Comment: With in that json

Comment: yes qty value in json

Comment: please check updated answer

Comment: it is giving empty value

Comment: please check now

Comment: $option_value_array = unserialize(urldecode($coll['value']));

Answer (score 0):

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item_option')->getCollection();
```

To get a single property value from every model in the collection:

$`collection->getColumnValues('your_column_name');`

Comment: Actually I want to fire a query where I have item_id 's value . So how to write sql query for sales_flat_quote_item option table?

Comment: yes, I got value, but problem is that I want to put where condition i.e item_id = 1